# проблема перерисовки JPanel

Tags: java, jpanel

я делаю игру где двигается очень много линий в таймере каждые 25 миллисекунд я перерисовываю JPanel paintComponent функцией repaint(). когда я запускаю программу у меня всё очень сильно лагает но когда я двигаю мышку перестаёт лагать потом опять лагает  а когда двигаю мышку перестаёт лагать и т.д. Я так понимаю что надо как-то сообщить системе что экран перерисовался. когда я двигаю мышку система знает что экран перисовался а у функции repaint я так понял нет.

Comment: Почему бы не добавить кода в вопрос?

Comment: @Agzam4
смысла добавлять кода нет, но если очень надо то вот: 

javax.swing.Timer repaint_timer = new javax.swing.Timer(25, new ActionListener() {
        Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            repaint();
        }
    });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Попробуйте это:

#### JPanel:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
import java.awt.event.ComponentListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Game extends JPanel {

    private static long sleep = 25; // 25 миллисекунд 
    boolean isThreadRunning;
    
    public void run() {
        Thread t = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                game = new BufferedImage(getWidth(), getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
                long start;
                long wait;
                while (true) {
                    start = System.nanoTime();
                    update();
                    draw();
                    wait = sleep - (System.nanoTime() - start)/1000000;
                    if(wait < 0) wait = 1;
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(wait);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        addComponentListener(new ComponentListener() {
            
            @Override
            public void componentShown(ComponentEvent arg0) {}
            @Override
            public void componentResized(ComponentEvent arg0) {
                if(isThreadRunning)
                    return;
                t.start();
                isThreadRunning = true;
            }
            @Override
            public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent arg0) {}
            @Override
            public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent arg0) {}
        });
    }

    private void update() {
        // Обновление игрового цикла
    };

    BufferedImage game;
    
    private void draw() {
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) game.getGraphics();
        // Отрисовка игры
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, game.getWidth(), game.getHeight());
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.drawString("Игра", game.getWidth()/2, game.getHeight()/2);
        g.dispose(); // Конец отрисовки
        
        // Перерисовывание "game" (BufferedImage) на JPanel
        Graphics2D gr = (Graphics2D) getGraphics();
        gr.drawImage(game, 0, 0, null);
    }
}
```

#### Main:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame gameFrame = new JFrame();
        gameFrame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        gameFrame.setUndecorated(true);
        Game game = new Game();
        gameFrame.setContentPane(game);
        gameFrame.setVisible(true);
        game.run();
    }
```